# puttng text next to multiple links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I though I had this working and that I had done it right, but when I looked in IE and Chrome web browsers it was not perfect. This does however function correctly in Firefox. I am working at modifying a function that uses javascript to display a different .png file depending on which thumbnail is clicked. I modified it so that that instead of clicking thumbnails one would click links. The issue in the code is at the bottom in the `H2` heading portion of the code. In IE and Chrome the text "choose" and the 2 links (Link_1 and Link_2) don't show up exactly next to each other, but instead the links show up a little higher. Also in Chrome and IE the links don't have that line underneath the link that we should see. I put this inside the heading `H2` because it gave me control over the text style of the text "choose". Could someone please tell me the right way to put the text "choose" next to these links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>clickLinks</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    H1 {line-height:0px;}
    H1 {padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm .2cm; }
    P {padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;}


    a {padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm .3cm;}
    body { width: 920px; margin: auto; }
    #imageWrap { 
         width: 930px; 
        height: 470px; 
        background: url('ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat; 
    }

  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" 

  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbnail').live("click", function() {
            $('#mainImage').hide();
            $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', "url('ajax-loader.gif')");
            var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() {
                $('#mainImage').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
                $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
                $('#mainImage').fadeIn();
            });
            return false; 
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <H2 style="font-family:Angency FB;color:#A8A8A8; font-size:14px">choose:
  <a href="picture_1.png" class="thumbnail"><img  
    alt="Link_1"/></a>
  <a href="picture_2.png" class="thumbnail"><img  
    alt="Link_2"/></a> 

  <div id="imageWrap">
    <img src="picture_1.png" WIDTH="930" HEIGHT="470" alt="Main Image" id="mainImage"/></p>
  </div>  </H2>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eux6U/).  You had the h2 tag surrounding everything...which you shouldn't need to do.

```
  <H2 style="font-family:Angency FB;color:#A8A8A8; font-size:14px">choose:</H2>
  <a href="picture_1.png" class="thumbnail"><img  
    alt="Link_1"/></a>
  <a href="picture_2.png" class="thumbnail"><img  
    alt="Link_2"/></a> 

   <div id="imageWrap">
    <img src="picture_1.png" WIDTH="930" HEIGHT="470" alt="Main Image" id="mainImage"/>              
  </div>
```

Also, your css was pointing at an h1 tag, which didn't exist.  I changed to to an h2 tag.

In the future, please be more clear with your questions.  It was very confusing, however, I believe this answers your question.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistakes. I put all that CSS in between the heading tags because that put the text (choose) on the same line as the links. If I put the </H1> right after choose:  then the word "choose" shows up above the links.

Comment: thanks, that fiddle site is great. Do you know why in Google and IE there are not lines underneath the live links?

Comment: It's because you're Link_1 and Link_2 are image tags, not text. I updated the fiddle.